# Is there a way to repeat a tiled map with libgdx

Tags: libgdx, tiled

Is there a built in way to make libgdx map renderer repeat the map at the edges?

I.e., at the very far edge, start drawing the leftmostpart all over again, and so on.

thanks in advance